# Error with ^2, says matrix should be square

Tags: matlab, plot

I wanted to plot the following

```
y=linspace(0,D,100)

temp=y^2;

plot(y,temp);
```

i am getting an error with `y^2`, it says matrix should be square.

is there another way to plot.

Answer (score 8):

You are not getting that error because of plot. You are getting it because of

```
temp=y^2
```

Instead, you should be using

```
temp=y.^2
```

`^` means matrix power. `.^` is elementwise power. You can find more about MATLAB operators [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operators.html).

Let's say you have a 3x3 matrix, magic(3).

```
A=magic(3)
A = 
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
```

Here is square of matrix A (which is A*A, as Dan suggested):

```
A^2
ans =

    91    67    67
    67    91    67
    67    67    91
```

Here is the matrix which contains squares of A's elements:

```
A.^2
ans =
    64     1    36
     9    25    49
    16    81     4
```

Comment: May be worth adding that `A^2` is the same as `A*A` (i.e. matrix multiplication with self) to the explanation since you have already written out a numerical example.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative to the above answer, you can consider the following case:

```
A = magic(3);

temp = bsxfun(@times,A,A);
```

which retrieves the same results as

```
temp = A.^2;
```

the `.` operator will apply your square element-wise. `bsxfun` makes exactly the same.

I hope this helps.